# How to solve functions error in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: formula, libreoffice, calc

I am trying to do a split expenses in libreoffice calc and I have referred to others people template. However, my LibreOffice Calc keeps showing error of "#value!".

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(K5:K55)),(1/$H$5:$H$55)*$D$5:$D$55))-SUMIF($F$5:$F$55,K4,$D$5:$D$55)
```

[image]

Comment: at first glance the if function is missing a third argument, but that should not be an issue so I guess it something in the SUMIF rows - can you add the value for the criteria K4

Comment: i have just uploaded another picture for more understanding. the k4 is the criteria

Comment: that part with e5h1:... doesn't look right probably missing a comma or something. Try pasting each part of the formula separately eg =SUM(...) , then =SUMIF(...) and you will see which part is wrong

Comment: i just corrected it but still failed. please kindly view pic again

Comment: Now the image shows the SUMIF function inside the SUM() - which is the correct form you want? Try writing the criteria in sumif as "=X" instead of H4. From the look of it the cell H4 is actually equal to A

Comment: I want to do a conditional sum by if there a x in A,then 1 divided by "No."  and multiple "Amount" respectively. Also, it minus the sumif as well in one line equation.

Comment: Please explain again what you are trying to achieve with 1 / <range>. In Excel, this "dirty hack" really works. Calc is much stricter about the results of intermediate calculations - if in the depth of the formula there was a "division by zero" error, then Calc does not consider it possible to return any result, it would be a deception of the user. Explain what you are trying to achieve, and perhaps it will be done with a simple `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: Not sure how the AMT column is formatted - it should be a number to do the calculations you want. And the criteria should be either H5 or "=X" because you want to check that the value is X, not A (which is the value of the H4 cell)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want an array operation. Finish the edit of the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, see [Array Functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC).